# How to change workspace name in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

**Is there any appropriate way to change workspace name in Xcode?**

Seems to me that it works to quit Xcode and manually change the `.xcworkspace` file from `OLD_NAME.xcworkspace` to `NEW_NAME.xcworkspace`.

Xcode 5 was used at the time of writing.

Comment: 2019, Beyond all belief, you can now just ***change the name of the file***.  Hard to believe but true.  Simply quit Xcode first - that's the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I reckon so.  As far as I can see, a workspace is just a reference to one or more Xcode projects and doesn't produce anything outside of those projects.

Answer (score 7):

## 2019:

First note that this question is about changing the name of an Xcode ***workspace***.  The QA is not about changing the name of a project, a project within a workspace, the source folder, or other aspects of naming in the Xcode milieu.

Xcode 11 and further.

Surprisingly, you can now just ***change the name of the file*** !  As strange as that seems.

1. Quit Xcode. You must do this first.
2. Using your mouse, and keyboard, change the name:

[image]

[image]

This causes no problem with Swift Package Manager or any other issue.

You now simply open the .xcworkspace file as normal.

One part of a fifteen year old Apple problem resolved!

Comment: Hey... just giving you a heads-up. This has always been the case.  The OP even mentioned it right in the body of their question back in 2013.  They weren't asking ***how*** do you rename a workspace, they were asking how do you rename a workspace ***from within Xcode***. Unfortunately, unlike IDEs from other vendors that expose their 'flavors' of workspaces right in the IDE, since Apple doesn't do so in Xcode (except when choosing the initial name), the answer is simply 'You can't.'

Comment: Quite simple solution. Worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

### Steps to Rename Workspace

1. Rename the Folder( contain all files) of Main Project
2. Rename the Workspace
3. delete the Xcode project from Workspace and re-add/Drag Xcode project again to Workspace. And in build setting rename “product name”
4. Now, In Workspace ,select the project  in general , option  for  selecting infoPlist  will appear, select the info plist of project. 
   then, Click the Manage Scheme and Create New Scheme with Xcode Project Name , check the New Created Scheme and delete the older one.
5. clear the both Xcode and Workspace ..and delete Derived  Data “~/Library/Developer/Xcode”
6. if project contain Bridging Header file then , just rename the Bridging Header file with With project name - “ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” and then open the Xcode project not workspace. In build settings.. in “Swift Compiler -Code Generation”—> Objective-C Bridging Header — “reset the Path of Bridging header file”. close the Xocde. And if Project Contain Pod File , then open Pod file rename the target name with new project .close both xocde project and Workspace project and install the pod.
7. now  open the Workspace clean and build.

Comment: If anyone runs into issues when attempting this excellent answer from @V12 (Ex: Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Linker command failed with exit code 1) Double check that you only have one scheme (the new one created when did you the above instructions) Also, double check that you only have one Pod framework linked in the Frameworks file of the project AS WELL as the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section in the general tab when you click on the top project (blue) icon. If there is only one framework built, you should be able to get a successful build

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same (XC6) but got a build error with one file not found. Not a huge issue, but for some it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: yes changing name of workplace is not issue but if u change name of folders along issues will start occurring not worth the effort. +1

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to **rename also the project inside the workspace** which had the same name.

For that it was important before renaming the project to..

- close Xcode
- rename the `.xcworkspace`-file from the Finder
- open Xcode with new named workspace
- rename the project inside the
  workspace with Xcode help by clicking on the project name

Answer (score 0):

I want to change the workspace name, project name and all linked file with old project name, so I tried the steps from this post, and it's really helpful

**Renaming an Xcode project with Pods: the easy way**
https://medium.com/programming-lite/renaming-an-xcode-9-project-with-pods-the-easy-way-5d1228ef25a